Help developing intuition behind sufficient statistics (Casella & Berger)
Migrated to Cross Validated
I am trying to understand the following intuition for sufficient statistics in Casella & Berger (2nd edition, pg. 272):

A sufficient statistic captures all of the information about $\theta$ in this sense. Consider Experimenter 1, who observes $\mathbf X=\mathbf x$ and, of course, can compute $T(\mathbf X)=T(\mathbf x)$. To make an inference about $\theta$ he can use the information that $\mathbf X=\mathbf x$ and $T(\mathbf X)=T(\mathbf x)$.  Now consider Experimenter 2, who is not told the value of $\mathbf X$ but only that $T(\mathbf X)=T(\mathbf x)$. Experimenter 2 knows $P(\mathbf X=\mathbf y|T(\mathbf X)=T(\mathbf x))$, a probability distribution on $A_{T(\mathbf x)}=\{\mathbf y:T(\mathbf y)=T(\mathbf x)\}$, because this can be computed from the model without knowledge of the true value of $\theta$. Thus, Experimenter 2 can use this distribution and a randomization device, such as a random number table, to generate an observation $\mathbf Y$ satisfying $P(\mathbf Y=\mathbf y|T(\mathbf X)=T(\mathbf x))=P(\mathbf X=\mathbf y|T(\mathbf X)=T(\mathbf x))$. It turns out that, for each value of $\theta$, $\mathbf X$ and $\mathbf Y$ have the same unconditional probability distribution, as we shall see below. So Experimenter 1, who knows $\mathbf X$, and Experimenter 2, who knows $\mathbf Y$, have equivalent information about $\theta$.

I understand that Experimenter 1 has access to the original observation $\mathbf x$ and can compute the sufficient statistic $T(\mathbf x)$, while Experimenter 2 is given only $T(\mathbf x)$.  Furthermore, I understand that by the definition of sufficient statistics the conditional distribution $P(\mathbf X=\mathbf y|T(\mathbf X)=T(\mathbf x))$ is independent of $\theta$ and thus only knowledge of $T(\mathbf x)$ is needed to generate random samples from this distribution.  Where I get hung up is why the fact that $\mathbf X$ and $\mathbf Y$ having the same unconditional distribution proves both experimenters have the same information about $\theta$.  I thought $\mathbf Y$ was distributed according to the conditional distribution and not the unconditional distribution. A proof of the fact that both $\mathbf X$ and $\mathbf Y$ have the same unconditional distribution is given further down in the text and, while I think I understand the proof, it doesn't feel like I have developed and understand the intuition here.
Perhaps an alternative explanation in someone else's words will get me over the hurdle here.

Suppose that the two experimenters are only "data collectors", and the "data analyst" is a different person.
Also suppose that experimenter 1 performed the experiments twice, generating $X_1$ and $X_2$. The "analyst" will have no means to differentiate these two data sets, because both contain the same amount of information.
Now experimenter 2 generated a "pseudo data set" $Y$, using only $T(X)$ and some random device. To the "analyst" who only sees $Y$, but not $T(X)$, this is just a third data set that behaves identically to the other two.
In this sense, $Y$ is compared unconditionally with $X$ (or with $X_1$ and $X_2$) by the "analyst". The conditionality trick is only known to experimenter 2, and can be treated as part of the data collection process.
